# Not able to receive multiple different random Strings from list in Java

Tags: java, random, while-loop

I want to code it so that the output of my code to output all of the Strings in a list in a random order, but not repeat and of them. I am hoping to do this with more than three variables, but to keep my question short, I only have three in this example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class TestingOutputs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean forever = true, one = true, two = true, three = true;
        List<String> outputsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        outputsList.add("One");
        outputsList.add("Two");
        outputsList.add("Three");

        while(forever){
            String outputsRandom = outputsList.get(new Random().nextInt(outputsList.size()));
            while(three) {
                if(outputsRandom.equals("Three")) {
                    System.out.println("This is three");
                    three = false;
                }
            while(two) {
                if(outputsRandom.equals("Two")) {
                    System.out.println("This is two");
                    two = false;
                }
            }
            while(one) {
                if(outputsRandom.equals("One")) {
                    System.out.println("This is one");
                    two = false;
                }
            }
            }
        }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create  a list of numbers starting from 0 to the numbers of strings.

```
List<Integer> range = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, outputsList.size() - 1)
    .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The shuffle the created list and get elements in a for-each loop.:

```
Collections.shuffle(range);
for(Integer i:range)
{
  outputsList.get(i.intValue());
}
```

The numbers would be random and non-repeating.
Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to clone your ArrayList, and randomly output the selected item, and then remove it.
In code, it would look like this:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Example {
  public static ArrayList<String> createList() {
    ArrayList<String> listTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
    listTemp.add("one");
    listTemp.add("two");
    listTemp.add("three");
    
    return listTemp;
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> listOutputs = createList();
    
    // Clone to not alter original list
    ArrayList<String> listTemp = (ArrayList<String>) listOutputs.clone();
    
    while (listTemp.size() != 0) {
      int index = (int) (Math.random() * listTemp.size());
      System.out.println("Selected element: '" + listTemp.get(index) + "'");
      listTemp.remove(index);
    }
  }
}
```

However, [Vishal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63733165/13561410) is by far a cleaner and more efficient way, especially with larger lists.